# Google Chrome cut off when print pdf

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing

As in title, Our web server often return pdf report to user. When they view that pdf report, they often print it by using Ctrl + P in chrome.

The problem is that when print pdf by chrome, it always cut off header and footer of the pdf page (~0.45 cm or 0.1771654 inches).

You could see image in bottom of this post, all content in two red rectangular will be lost when we press "Print" (although it displays fine in print preview).

I have searched for keyword "Chrome cut off when print pdf" and found some topic about this in google productforums (2011, 2016,...), all have no solutions, and often become locked topic so can't reply to that.

So if someone know anyway to fix that, please answer this.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Are you sure about *"~0.45 mm"*? The framed regions in your image look much bigger...

Comment: @mkl Sorry, it's 0.45 cm. Edited. Thank you

Comment: Have you checked whether your printer can print so near to the page border? There are numerous printers out there that simply cannot print in those regions...

Comment: @mkl. After reading your comment I have searched and found about _borderless printing_ and [this topic about hp laser jet](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/LaserJet-Printing/borderless-printing/td-p/5868786). Sad because we and many of our customers use that hp laserjet product. Must redesign out report now and add margin to page for those cut off. Thank you!

Comment: Ok. I'll make my comment an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all printers can print on the whole paper sheet area, many have a small border area where they cannot print.

As it turned out in particular HP LaserJet printers don't support borderless printing (cf. [this HP support forum entry](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/LaserJet-Printing/borderless-printing/td-p/5868786) found by the op), and the op and his customers use such printers.

Thus,  the only sure work-around is designing one's PDFs with a white border.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Chrome crops an oversized PDF (not matching the paper size, and/or having text in the unprintable area), while most external applications scale it down by default. Thus, printing from Chrome fails, while first saving and then printing elsewhere works. Some possible workarounds:

- on the server, generate the PDF files in the correct paper size, and leaving adequate margins on the borders. In practice, one might need to know the target paper size.
- on the server, force using an external viewer by adding the header `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=foo.pdf` (Untested; when the user opens the file, it might still open in Chrome in some circumstances)
- instruct the user to print the file in an external application.

None of these solutions seem perfect to me.

Comment: I have the same problem. Chrome somehow cuts off or doesnt scale properly. I had to use another PDF program which printed it totally correct, where Chrome doesnt.